# R access to columns of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a big `data.table` df consisting of Integer values between 0 and 1 and I'd like to change some of the columns. These are named as shown below. I would like to do this for 10 scaling factors, also integer, so  I thought a loop would be more efficient. I used the package `data.table`.

Cur_1  Cur_2  Cur_3  Cur_4  Cur_5  Cur_6  Cur_7  Cur_8  Cur_9  Cur_10  Cur_11  Cur_12

0.225   0.227      0.229  0.233  0.225  0.226  0.228  0.229  0.229  0.301   0.302   0.305

0.226   0.227     0.229  0.233  0.225  0.226  0.228  0.229  0.229  0.301   0.302   0.305

```
if(pd_scaling1!=0){
df$Cur_1=df$Cur_1*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_2=df$Cur_2*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_3=df$Cur_3*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_4=df$Cur_4*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_5=df$Cur_5*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_6=df$Cur_6*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_7=df$Cur_7*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_8=df$Cur_8*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_9=df$Cur_9*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_10=df$Cur_10*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_11=df$Cur_11*(1+scaling1)
df$Cur_12=df$Cur_12*(1+scaling1)
}
```

I tried this:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  if(get(paste("scaling",i,sep=""))!=0){
    for(j in (i-1)*12+1:i*12){
         df[,get(paste("Cur",j,sep="_")):=get(paste("Cur",j,sep="_"))*rep((1+get(paste("scaling",i,sep=""))),h_i)
    }
  }
```

But got the following error:

> Error in get(paste("Cur", j, sep = "_")) : object 'Cur_2' not found
>       }

Comment: Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and fix your question in order to make it possible for us to help you.

Comment: Please read the data.table vignettes. They show how to properly loop over columns.

Comment: @Roland could you please send me a link, I couln't find it in [data.table vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)

Comment: See 2.e in that vignette and 2.e in [this one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html).

Comment: @abhiieor thanks for the tip, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is the first thing that came to my mind (and maybe not the optimal solution) of applying the scale value to the columns in the `data.table` given a condition.

First I created a `data.table` based on your data:

```
library(data.table)
names <- sapply(1:12,function(x) paste0("Cur_",x))
d1 <- c(0.225, 0.227, 0.229, 0.233, 0.225, 0.226, 0.228, 0.229, 0.229, 0.301, 0.302, 0.305)
d2 <- c(0.226, 0.227, 0.229, 0.233, 0.225, 0.226, 0.228, 0.229, 0.229, 0.301, 0.302, 0.305)
D <- sapply(1:12, function(x) list(d1[x], d2[x]))
DD <- data.table(D)
colnames(DD) <- names
head(DD)
```

The `data.table` look like this:

```
   Cur_1 Cur_2 Cur_3 Cur_4 Cur_5 Cur_6 Cur_7 Cur_8 Cur_9 Cur_10 Cur_11 Cur_12
1: 0.225 0.227 0.229 0.233 0.225 0.226 0.228 0.229 0.229  0.301  0.302  0.305
2: 0.226 0.227 0.229 0.233 0.225 0.226 0.228 0.229 0.229  0.301  0.302  0.305
```

I suppose that you are trying to apply a scale value to all the columns, so I create a scaling variable with a random number of the same length of the columns in the `data.table`.

```
scaling <- rep(100,length(names))
```

I have see that you are trying to verify if the scale value is different to 0, so I intentionally put one of the scale values to 0, just for show the behaviour of the solution I made.

```
scaling[2] <- 0
```

Now we create a loop that verify the value of the scaling and apply the scale to the columns of the `data.table`

```
for (i in 1:length(names)) {
    if (scaling[i] != 0) {
        DD[,names[i] := lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(x)*scaling[i]), .SDcols = names[i]]
    }
}
```

The final `data.table` looks like this:

```
head(DD)
 Cur_1 Cur_2 Cur_3 Cur_4 Cur_5 Cur_6 Cur_7 Cur_8 Cur_9 Cur_10 Cur_11 Cur_12
1:  22.5 0.227  22.9  23.3  22.5  22.6  22.8  22.9  22.9   30.1   30.2   30.5
2:  22.6 0.227  22.9  23.3  22.5  22.6  22.8  22.9  22.9   30.1   30.2   30.5
```

**Some tips:** I highly suggest you to read the source provided by **David Arenburg**, because I had to guess what were the things you wanted.
The source of **Roland** in the comments is very useful and explains well the solution to your problem.